# Whose neighbours are hostile?

Tags: code-golf, array, arithmetic, integer, matrix

### Introduction

For the purposes of this challenge, we will define the *neighbours* of an element \$E\$ in a square matrix \$A\$ (such that \$E=A_{i,j}\$) as all the entries of \$A\$  that are immediately adjacent diagonally, horizontally or vertically to \$E\$ (i.e. they *"surround"* \$E\$, without wrapping around).

For pedants, a formal definition of the neighbours of \$A_{i,\:j}\$ for an \$n\times n\$ matix \$A\$ is (0-indexed):
$$N_{i,\:j}=\{A_{a,\:b}\mid(a,b)\in E_{i,\:j}\:\cap\:([0,\:n)\:\cap\:\Bbb{Z})^2\}$$
where
$$E_{i,\:j}=\{i-1,\:i,\:i+1\}\times \{j-1,\:j,\:j+1\} \text{ \\ } \{i,\:j\}$$

Let's say that the element at index \$i,\:j\$ lives in hostility if it is coprime to *all* its neighbours (that is, \$\gcd(A_{i,\:j},\:n)=1\:\forall\:n\in N_{i,\:j}\$). Sadly, this poor entry can't borrow even a cup of sugar from its rude nearby residents...

### Task

Enough stories: Given a square matrix \$M\$ of positive integers, output one of the following:

- A flat list of elements (deduplicated or not) indicating all entries that occupy some indices \$i,j\$ in \$M\$ such that the neighbours \$N_{i,\:j}\$ are hostile.
- A boolean matrix with \$1\$s at positions where the neighbours are hostile and \$0\$ otherwise (you can choose any other consistent values in place of \$0\$ and \$1\$).
- The list of pairs of indices \$i,\:j\$ that represent hostile neighbourhoods.

[Reference Implementation in Physica](https://tio.run/##fZLfbtMwGMWvm6c4RDC1moqSdB0oplMr0FAnQBNI3GS5aINhblNnyh8BSi3tclzzCogH64uUL7bXpYwhJXIcn@@czz/76vJ7IZLZdntayQTvuPhyOc@qvIgmIVJRlAwihJA0LvQYIzQLodOROzVGqJXTOc1y5NlXbG5uUIu@T8X0HPqKxJ3pZzzqetj8@KU1L/CGy/Gk9lQvRJLJUsiKk6zxSLK0Wkljs2hsFvRYm7aP1WkrjKHNsF6jSwHMrvYwGqFLfSz2c9rdH1L7k5qKVG2KFG3mPS@rXOJO5jiOhvT65atoZqHM76DQSP3RIsHwDYul3kIUYHP9G2@FjOoZlag4tjxmeEIa6m9@@@HpLRqT5a4HmlP4albm4hstTOVVVT52pvKTSLhl30YfeTqQoESmJu77TeRfaB@SdXjKV1yWZGz@75FxOvvn3royRs3Qoh@TPMmucrHipJ2kadTtn2AZaog2h2EZN3v3exiPW7yb2vOcsEYtQwZ3c/3TZdgVu/0Tmn4o86hV@jRdVEUZDYYxCdZuU62biA14OzP3yWJsLsHexVGOY@LdC3khz7OiEPOUI6tKwl@Ebny7/JHnhcgk/JCC6n8wgz0d1sZvc9U9m0Db1N0pw1mvLcXBAfzmfnva8OyBU0Qffmwyp/@V3EseNMk2LN5u6/r4iMH36D1S1FLwjCEIGAZBMxsOGIbPaXas1B8) – supports [Python](https://tio.run/##fZLfbtMwFMavm6f4iGBKtRbVrbZBQqdWoKFOgCaQuPF80QbD3KZOlT8ClEba5bjmFRAP1hcpJ47XpYwhRXKc853vO/7Fq6vvqQqn2@1ZrkO8k@rL1SzOk5SPfUQqzQIoH0rTOjergF8XfKeld2oMUZRO6yxOkMRfsbm5QaG6jJrpOWQliVuTz3jk9bD58ctoXuCN1KNx0SvbPsJYZ0rnkmSVRxhH@VLXNvPKZk6PtWn6WJ2xwgjGDOs1PAoIbLWN4RAezTHfz2lOf0jjjwtqKou6qaTDvJdZnmjcyRzHMZBev3zFpxbK7A4KrTQfFQkGq1kszBF4H5vr33irNC@m1FIKYXlM8YQ0NN/s9qVnjlibLHYz0J7Cl9MsUd@oMNGrPHvsTPQnFUrLvome90wgQeF1j@iyKvIvtA/JWjKSS6kzMq6/75FxWvv/vXFlanWABn1B8jBeJWopSTuOIu51T7HwDUSbE2AhqrOzNkajBu@q9yIhrLxhGMDdXP90A@ya3e4pbT9kCW@0Po3meZrxwZEgwdqtus0QogZvd/V9shirS7B3cUrHWZl491Jf6os4TdUskojzjPCnvituyx9lkqpYg/kUVPyDGezfCZr4bW55z6ZvbApvEuC83ZTi4ACsut89Y3j@wF9EF0zUmZP/Su4lD6pkGya2W84Hzzo4OemAMdEBZ/R2xDoY9Kvd8THVqM6eC/EH) syntax as well for I/O. You can take input and provide output through any [standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and in any reasonable format, while taking note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default. This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes (in every language) wins!

Moreover, you can take the matrix size as input too and additionally can take the matrix as a flat list since it will always be square.

### Example

Consider the following matrix:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
64 & 10 & 14 \\
27 & 22 & 32 \\
53 & 58 & 36 \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

The corresponding neighbours of each element are:

```
i j – E  -> Neighbours                          | All coprime to E?
                                                |
0 0 – 64 -> {10; 27; 22}                        | False
0 1 – 10 -> {64; 14; 27; 22; 32}                | False
0 2 – 14 -> {10; 22; 32}                        | False
1 0 – 27 -> {64; 10; 22; 53; 58}                | True
1 1 – 22 -> {64; 10; 14; 27; 32; 53; 58; 36}    | False
1 2 – 32 -> {10; 14; 22; 58; 36}                | False
2 0 – 53 -> {27; 22; 58}                        | True
2 1 – 58 -> {27; 22; 32; 53; 36}                | False
2 2 – 36 -> {22; 32; 58}                        | False
```

And thus the output must be one of the following:

- `{27; 53}`
- `{{0; 0; 0}; {1; 0; 0}; {1; 0; 0}}`
- `{(1; 0); (2; 0)}`

### Test cases

```
Input –> Version 1 | Version 2 | Version 3

[[36, 94], [24, 69]] ->
    []
    [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    []
[[38, 77, 11], [17, 51, 32], [66, 78, 19]] –>
    [38, 19]
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
    [(0, 0), (2, 2)]
[[64, 10, 14], [27, 22, 32], [53, 58, 36]] ->
    [27, 53]
    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
    [(1, 0), (2, 0)]
[[9, 9, 9], [9, 3, 9], [9, 9, 9]] ->
    []
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    []
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] ->
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] or [1]
    [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
    [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[[35, 85, 30, 71], [10, 54, 55, 73], [80, 78, 47, 2], [33, 68, 62, 29]] ->
    [71, 73, 47, 29]
    [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
    [(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Borrowing stuff from hostile neighbors? For some reason, this reminds me of Jeff Minter's game [Hover Bovver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hover_Bovver)...

Comment: Can we take the matrix size as input?

Comment: @Delfad0r I always forget to mention that. Yes, you may take the matrix size as input.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```
1=⊢∨(×/∘,↓)⌺3 3÷⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NSgNBEIX3nuLtpguUdHVN/0TIYQZkRByIhGyCuJMhUQMRF2YbV15AhGxzk7rI2KODxlVVvVdfvapumrOLRdVML7uu1nbDE3140@W7ObyOdLk91faF9GkvkMNndrpunpdudf2hq90st7Wu9@fF9LrQx/uirq6aIgvZnt2dGG2fjSTECGYyHOEZ4siEgJjAY6J5v8KwsGTsX2H6gUMJzlNJxkU49w17gU@QMMADxcdlSPZIHmIR@3ALX8J7RCGTbJ9f5pNkRBASgoMbH1/ML/xv@PfFrHwB) (credits to ngn for translating the test cases to APL)

#### Brief explanation

`(×/∘,↓)⌺3 3` gets the product of each element with its neighbours.

Then I divide by the argument `÷⊢`, so that each entry in the matrix has been mapped to the product of its neighbors.

Finally I take the gcd of the argument with this matrix `⊢∨`, and check for equality with 1, `1=`

Note, as with [ngn's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172275/71256), this fails for some inputs due to a bug in the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 121 bytes

Returns a matrix of Boolean values, where *false* means hostile.

```javascript
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>[...'12221000'].some((k,j,a)=>(g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a>1)(v,(m[y+~-k]||0)[x+~-a[j+2&7]]||1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZFNbsIwEIX3PYU3LbYYQmwTByqFHsTywmkBFQhBUCGQUK@ePidUBYJU2siR34x/vueZud/57evmff3RW5Vvk2qaVUU2LqLCrznf0EFk400T7GiPwEZR1JFKKRnHccdF27KYcL6gOXms8lnGPeVQ@cuM5@Qfc/Hsx1LgNC/sofvZW7jjMRZ2D@ntvKueUoeMFPiq13K1LZeTaFnO@JRbqw2x0cARs2pAzIycE4L94@v3mbUxsThcVc/uocUaEktTYlKGTRIqkcS0CpGBjxTr8g4HNQsnz3EXUt6AGzxPhrXmsYAr9Q1PNKwArs2d8DOibMs2fIQiY4RNmPWPrLP3l/wafkO24bAVxsnhtfwj/JfL2j1PiA3xa5hLm71QCZqRIJvqkBnGTe8HoSkhoVEhg4RBh1RTn/OXn6C3InlZjdpT9QU)

#### How?

The method used to isolate the 8 neighbors of each cell is similar to [the one I described here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168817/58563).

#### Commented

```javascript
m =>                            // m[] = input matrix
  m.map((r, y) =>               // for each row r[] at position y in m[]:
    r.map((v, x) =>             //   for each value v at position x in r[]:
      [...'12221000']           //     we consider all 8 neighbors
      .some((k, j, a) =>        //     for each k at position j in this array a[]:
        ( g = (a, b) =>         //       g is a function which takes 2 integers a and b
            b ?                 //       and recursively determines whether they are
              g(b, a % b)       //       coprime to each other
            :                   //       (returns false if they are, true if they're not)
              a > 1             //
        )(                      //       initial call to g() with:
          v,                    //         the value of the current cell
          (m[y + ~-k] || 0)     //         and the value of the current neighbor
          [x + ~-a[j + 2 & 7]]  //
          || 1                  //         or 1 if this neighbor is undefined
  ))))                          //         (to make sure it's coprime with v)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 22 bytes

```
tTT1&Ya3thYC5&Y)Zd1=A)
```

Input is a matrix. Output is all numbers with hostile neighbours.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQkxFAtMtG4JCPS2VQtUjMqxdDWUfP//2hjCx0Fc3MdBUNDawVDIG1qqKNgbGStYGYGFAfKGVrGAgA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XU4xCsMwDNzzCk0JAQciK5ZjRIfSPiFD0xBooEOHdsv/3TOhS0GyJN/pTp9tf@dH3qeJ63mT/TVfQj239yefzm1uuq65Xae8iDpKg5EfHGlaqVpkdBSjI2YjRg3sSLyRghmBcVqrRUHnHllWQfL@IAXBAkiiICVII6y88mtKAINoCaP/BpgERyNSYBALghpgGPAXxWjsj0uGYmwk0FaMiht8Wr8).

#### Explanation with worked example

Consider input `[38, 77, 11; 17, 51, 32; 66, 78, 19]` as an example. Stack contents are shown bottom to top.

```
t         % Implicit input. Duplicate
          % STACK: [38, 77, 11;
                    17, 51, 32;
                    66, 78, 19]
                   [38, 77, 11;
                    17, 51, 32;
                    66, 78, 19]
TT1&Ya    % Pad in the two dimensions with value 1 and width 1
          % STACK: [38, 77, 11;
                    17, 51, 32;
                    66, 78, 19]
                   [1,  1,  1,  1,  1;
                    1,  38, 77, 11, 1;
                    1,  17, 51, 32, 1;
                    1,  66, 78, 19, 1
                    1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
3thYC     % Convert each sliding 3×3 block into a column (in column-major order)
          % STACK: [38, 77, 11;
                    17, 51, 32;
                    66, 78, 19]
                   [ 1,  1,  1,  1, 38, 17,  1, 77, 51;
                     1,  1,  1, 38, 17, 66, 77, 51, 78;
                     1,  1,  1, 17, 66,  1, 51, 78,  1;
                     1, 38, 17,  1, 77, 51,  1, 11, 32;
                    38, 17, 66, 77, 51, 78, 11, 32, 19;
                    17, 66,  1, 51, 78,  1, 32, 19,  1;
                     1, 77, 51,  1, 11, 32,  1,  1,  1;
                    77, 51, 78, 11, 32, 19,  1,  1,  1;
                    51, 78,  1, 32, 19,  1,  1,  1,  1]
5&Y)      % Push 5th row (centers of the 3×3 blocks) and then the rest of the matrix
          % STACK: [38, 77, 11;
                    17, 51, 32;
                    66, 78, 19]
                   [38, 17, 66, 77, 51, 78, 11, 32, 19]
                   [ 1,  1,  1,  1, 38, 17,  1, 77, 51;
                     1,  1,  1, 38, 17, 66, 77, 51, 78;
                     1,  1,  1, 17, 66,  1, 51, 78,  1;
                     1, 38, 17,  1, 77, 51,  1, 11, 32;
                    17, 66,  1, 51, 78,  1, 32, 19,  1;
                     1, 77, 51,  1, 11, 32,  1,  1,  1;
                    77, 51, 78, 11, 32, 19,  1,  1,  1;
                    51, 78,  1, 32, 19,  1,  1,  1,  1]
Zd        % Greatest common divisor, element-wise with broadcast
          % STACK: [38, 77, 11;
                    17, 51, 32;
                    66, 78, 19]
                   [1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1;
                    1,  1,  1,  1, 17,  6, 11,  1,  1;
                    1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  1,  1,  2,  1;
                    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  1,  1,  1;
                    1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1;
                    1,  1,  3,  1,  1,  2,  1,  1,  1;
                    1, 17,  6, 11,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1;
                    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
1=        % Compare with 1, element-wise. Gives true (1) or false (0)
          % STACK: [38, 77, 11;
                    17, 51, 32;
                    66, 78, 19]
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
                    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1;
                    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1;
                    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1;
                    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1;
                    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1;
                    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
                    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
A         % All: true (1) for columns that do not contain 0
          % STACK: [38, 77, 11;
                    17, 51, 32;
                    66, 78, 19]
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
)         % Index (the matrix is read in column-major order). Implicit display
          % [38, 19]
```

Comment: Will this work if the matrix is bigger than 3x3?

Comment: @RobertFraser Yes, the procedure does not depend on matrix size. See last test case for example

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @H.PWiz

```apl
{∧/1=1↓∨∘⊃⍨1⌈4⌽,⍵}⌺3 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NSsNQEIX3fYqzy71gMXN/E8GHCZVIMFBpuxHpSglRE1FEcOPClX2Bbgq@zLxIvImN1s38nJlvzmSX5fTsKivn59NZmS2Xxazjx9diztVT3OUhXnP9eUynxNUL1xuu3/j@htsNcVMbbr6OuN2uudlp6K5bDfvtlu8@FqHMud2dRPOLiB9uozwryigIYbxYT7h9F1w9C@2QGimUgUulXPVSjFgOYfKzkcB7EElBHpaglRTOwSegkSCMzJhoDzsDCl3v4KHUAFsNm0C7P7ueosO0d7ZILHQM35vHsAbWwmspkrj3N@GkFFrDJXAKKj28GF74X9Dvi0H5Bg)

doesn't support matrices smaller than 3x3 due to [a bug](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/52405?m=42700294#42700294) in the interpreter

Comment: @H.PWiz that's very smart, do you wanna post it as your own?

Comment: Sure, you can also use `(⊃∨⊢)` -> `∨∘⊂⍨` I think

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Hmm, seems long.</sup>

```
ỊẠ€T
ŒJ_€`Ç€ḟ"J$ịFg"FÇịF
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of positive integers which returns a list of each of the values which are in hostile neighbourhoods (version 1 with no de-duplication).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU4xDoIwFN05RUMcO9CWtnABTJjdGqKLMTFcwNWFRDcmNz2AB1BxIxykXqS@UoiDyS99vPd@39tv6/rgnO1O9nX7HO@raGjLNcCmb/C1j2tcLmx3LnZx0TceuOE9SkNrnxfcmKVzxhihKMnTihLDU0pUXlU0IqAzSrSmhDEvMSDJKBHc/ymsaOhsNitssgQnvAMz57NZCqzCLNRkzpGH8Rpu8YMjGzyI8jNG/8OpoaQkwxEI1kEHkqgiwWrhmSwJTVNfyRMCeQqEQj@OtOoL)** Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##ZU4xDoIwFN05RUMcO9CWtnABTJjdGqKLMTFcwNWFRDcmNz2AB1BxIxykXqS@UoiDyS99vPd@39tv6/rgnO1O9nX7HO@raGjLNcCmb/C1j2tcLmx3LnZx0TceuOE9SkNrnxfcmKVzxhihKMnTihLDU0pUXlU0IqAzSrSmhDEvMSDJKBHc/ymsaOhsNitssgQnvAMz57NZCqzCLNRkzpGH8Rpu8YMjGzyI8jNG/8OpoaQkwxEI1kEHkqgiwWrhmSwJTVNfyRMCeQqEQj@OtOoL).

#### How?

```
ỊẠ€T - Link 1: indices of items which only contain "insignificant" values: list of lists
Ị    - insignificant (vectorises) -- 1 if (-1<=value<=1) else 0 
  €  - for €ach:
 Ạ   -   all?
   T - truthy indices

ŒJ_€`Ç€ḟ"J$ịFg"FÇịF - Main Link: list of lists of positive integers, M
ŒJ                  - multi-dimensional indices
    `               - use as right argument as well as left...
   €                -   for €ach:
  _                 -     subtract (vectorises)
      €             - for €ach:
     Ç              -   call last Link (1) as a monad
          $         - last two links as a monad:
         J          -   range of length -> [1,2,3,...,n(elements)]
        "           -   zip with:
       ḟ            -     filter discard (remove the index of the item itself)
            F       - flatten M
           ị        - index into (vectorises) -- getting a list of lists of neighbours
               F    - flatten M
              "     - zip with:
             g      -   greatest common divisor
                Ç   - call last Link (1) as a monad
                  F - flatten M
                 ị  - index into
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>182</s> <s>177</s> 166 bytes

```python
lambda a:[[all(gcd(t,a[i+v][j+h])<2for h in[-1,0,1]for v in[-1,0,1]if(h|v)*(i+v>-1<j+h<len(a)>i+v))for j,t in E(s)]for i,s in E(a)]
from fractions import*
E=enumerate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDLbsIwEDyXr/ANGxYJ28QBlHDjK1wfXEhIUF4yLlKl/nu6m7RqpUq2MjOeyax2@IhV36mxzF/HxrdvV8/80VrfNPx2ufII3tbrp7P3deVEpso@sIrVnd1I2IJ0xJ9/eF3y6vMpVhxDp43MMJY1Rce9OKEiBPnvEDHBzvwhpnwNj5l74RZl6FtWBn@Jdd@h3g59iKvFOS@697YIPhYjZTwlrLXaADvsHDCrdsDMwRG0eg8sTYFJSVQiSiQwrYgZTKT4Lr@9BnNyi3f@C3qV@vEmGpPo1Wb2HrAMD2H86l84qZMFe@hMvf/hPF0CbI9XY2s6PyNKcI4E1VSTst/OU@5oHhI0thkUDA6nsMsdFy9DqLvIPCzz0xJs6weOHMK05EALKmml4/gF)

Outputs a list of lists with True/False entries.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 95 bytes

```hs
m?n|l<-[0..n-1]=[a|i<-l,j<-l,a<-[m!!i!!j],2>sum[1|u<-l,v<-l,(i-u)^2+(j-v)^2<4,gcd(m!!u!!v)a>1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDBboUgELy/r1iTHjDFFwFFTdT3Bf0CShPTNi1WiKlPT/673dXYHpoAu8zMMhM@u@nrfRi2zd/COtSJSa/XkAjbmG51dTLwno4OCR9FLop6y2U7zd6IdSZmoYO5ZI5f5CPrkwVrnfGP1zeGA3MULXHXCms3F8b5PjWGGaM0hyqzHIzMOOjK4psxJ6LkUBQchCBSYJcLDkrSTeNQgbwgudrlGqdFivt4C@VSnvJc4TDKlf6VV@iKi1is6q/d0VOFhrT2AP/bU6VyDiVuhfbFocAux0A5ooUipEyPxBkFI0Chp0ZAY0pJjllsLxffuQAN@G58AvbMPIcQQ9LC@O3CHR7Aw42Q4/@2Hw)

The function `?` takes the matrix `m` as a list of lists and the matrix size `n`; it returns the list of entries *in hostility*.